# pass parameter is field after where mysql , procedure

Tags: mysql, procedure

I do my filter with column of table pass through parameter(field after where in line 7) procedure but pass parameter column of table ,mysql doesn't know

```
use testphantrang;
DELIMITER $$
CREATE PROCEDURE `filter`(in field varchar(40), in giatri varchar(40),in index_of_page int)
begin
        declare xx int ;
        set xx = index_of_page*15;
        SELECT * from test where field like CONCAT('%', giatri,'%') limit xx,15;
END; $$
DELIMITER ;
call `filter`('email','b',0);
```

Below is my table:

[image]

Comment: You can use CONCAT to join the strings like CONCAT("SELECT * from test where ", field, " like CONCAT('%'," ,giatri,"'%') limit", xx ,",15")

Comment: it's redundant single quote mark  .MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near 'b'%') limit0,15' at line 1.need to delete 2 single quote mark next to b @@

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
DELIMITER $$
CREATE PROCEDURE `filter`(in field varchar(40), in giatri varchar(40),in index_of_page int)
begin
        declare xx int ;
        set xx = index_of_page*15;

       set @query = CONCAT('SELECT * from test where field rlike ''', giatri,''' limit ',xx,',15;');

 PREPARE dynamic_statement FROM @query;
 EXECUTE dynamic_statement;
 DEALLOCATE PREPARE dynamic_statement;
END; $$
DELIMITER ;


call `filter`('email','b',0);
```